# Flux via cURL will not run if the input data file contains import statement

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

Following is working in REPL mode:

```
influx -precision rfc3339 -type=flux -path-prefix=/api/v2/query

> bName = "benchmark_db/autogen"
> import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"
> v1.measurements(bucket: bName)
```

I would like to wrap the query. According to this [doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/guides/execute-queries/#influxdb-api), I created a script called demo.flux under /home/demo.flux and put the above content in it and initiate following statement:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:8086/api/v2/query -sS -H 'Accept:application/csv' -H 'Content-type:application/vnd.flux' --data-binary "@/home/demo.flux"
```

However, it returns with an error:

```
error
loc 3:1-3:7: invalid statement @3:1-3:7: import
```

Answer (score 1):

`import` statement must be first, before any other declarations.

Comment: thx, tried with your suggestion and it works.